# CSS - One-level dropdown menu

Tags: css, menu, styling

I'm designing Wordpress themes, the only and ever problem I have is dropdown menus.
styling those "ul" and "li" selectors with "display" and... properties.
Even reading tutorials and looking at other websites's CSS (Firebug), I still can't create one!
Is there any particular procedure or good source I can learn it?
Suppose I want to design a one-level dropdown menu.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Mahdi,

Creating a cross-browser compatible dropdown menu is quite simple as long as you don't over-complicate it and have a decent understanding element types and the positioning model in CSS. There are some standard examples that can make it quite easy for you as well. I will try and provide as simple an answer as possible for you to understand (as my brain overcomplicated it for a LOOOONG time until I did a little research).

**Your Top-Level Menu**

It is good practice to have all of your *menus* including submenus be a `ul` element. There are a couple of reasons for this.

1. It naturally has most of the style that you need.
2. A menu is a list of options anyway, so its not a stretch to make it a list.
3. It helps disabled individuals
4. It allows for nesting.

The problem with `ul` elements is they have those nasty bullets. Additionally, the `li` children don't naturally flow together. They all appear on separate lines. So, we have two options to fix the `li`. We can `float` them, but that can get quite awkward. I don't recommend it. Or we can change its type. Well, we're containing another block in it, so an `inline-block` is kinda perfect for this.

```
<!-- the HTML for the menu -->
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="submenu"><a href="url">link</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="url">link</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="url">link</a></li>
</ul>

/* The CSS for the menu */
ul.menu { 
    list-style-type:none; /* Gets rid of the bullets. */
}
li.submenu {
    display:inline-block; /* Makes the listitems appear on the same row. */
}
```

** Your Sub-menus**

Now, nested `ul` elements must be in a list item. Browsers will always interpret it correctly if you place your dropdown `ul` in a `li` itself. Now, we don't have to declare anything funny. Just name your new `ul` the same as your original menu, like so:

```
<!-- Your new HTML -->
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="submenu"><a href="url">link</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="url">link</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="url">link</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

/* Your new CSS. Notice nothing has changed. */
ul.menu { 
    list-style-type:none; /* Gets rid of the bullets. */
}
ul.menu li {
    display:inline-block; /* Makes the listitems appear on the same row. */
}
```

**The next step. Getting the drop down to appear.**

Now, we have our cross-browser structure, we just need to tweak a couple of things. We need to first make the menu appear and disappear. Since we only want this to happen to a submenu, we get more specific:

```
/* Add this to your CSS. */
li.submenu ul.menu {
    display:none; /* Makes the submenu disappear. */
}
li.submenu:hover ul.menu {
    display:block; /* Makes the submenu appear. */
}
```

Now, if you take a look, your menu appears and disappears appropriately. No styling, just lists for you. Works the same way in all of the browsers... oh wait! IE is making it bigger. Well, that's a simple issue. You see, IE interprets padding differently than the others. Lets make it a non-issue:

```
/* Add this to your CSS. */
menu * {
    padding:0; /* Width problem solved. */
}
```

Now, one other issue... your submenus are horizontal. The reason is because we told it is should be in our original.

```
ul.menu li {
    display:inline-block; /* Makes the listitems appear on the same row. */
}
```

We can fix this my being more specific.

```
/* Add this to your CSS. */
li.submenu ul.menu li {
    display:block;
}
```

Now it is vertical! Test this in any major browser and you will see those are the only components necessary for a cross-browser dropdown menu.

**Final HTML for Menu**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="submenu"><a href="url">link</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="url">link</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="url">link</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
            <li><a href="url">link</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Final CSS for Menu**

```
menu * {
    padding:0; /* Width problem solved. */
}

ul.menu { 
    list-style-type:none; /* Gets rid of the bullets. */
}
li.submenu {
    display:inline-block; /* Makes the listitems appear on the same row. */
}

li.submenu ul.menu {
    display:none; /* Makes the submenu disappear. */
}
li.submenu:hover ul.menu {
    display:block; /* Makes the submenu appear. */
}

li.submenu ul.menu li {
    display:block;
}
```

This solution doesn't require funny positioning or width declarations.

Hope this helps!

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: +10 for a great answer, + another 10 for putting in the effort to _make it_ such a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

One good source for me was http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/
You can see the basic structure used.

Comment: Thanks but just got headache !!

Comment: It is not easy to create a "simple" menu in CSS that is cross-browser compatible :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just create a simple one-level menu. It's kind of explained above by Fuzzical Logic but you can use the pseudo-class `:hover` to show and hide the dropdown menu. It's [explained in this article](http://www.shingokko.com/blog-entry/pure-css-hover-menu.html) in simple terms.

Hope it helps